# Creating mobile-applications (like Android applications) with Drupal?

Tags: mobile-tools

First, sorry if the question seems a bit basic to veteran programmers here - I'm just a newbie student for JS programming and not that of a big user of smartphone applications in general, at least not yet :) . I'm also not experienced in PHP programming (have yet to actually try that) and just in my first steps to getting to know this whole world now.

I want to know if it's possible, or at least practical to create smartphone (and maybe even web) applications with Drupal, at least with Drupal 8. Please give the most basic and general detailing you can.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this goal with services. Luckily Drupal 8 got services in core. All you need is to call your services from your android app. If you want to use Drupal 7 then you have to install and configure services module or restfull services.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to take a look at [DrupalGap](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap)

Also especially regarding Drupal 8 I would recommend reading this [article](https://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-4/issue-2/html-css-javascript-mobile-web-app):